# Angular2 pipe dynamic value not taking

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a json like this

```
[{
  "id": 9156,
  "slug": "chicken-seekh-wrap",
  "type": "dish",
  "title": "Chicken Seekh Wrap",
  "cuisine_type": [2140]
},
{
  "id": 9150,
  "slug": "green-salad",
  "type": "dish",
  "title": "Green Salad",
  "cuisine_type": [2141]
}]
```

I created a pipe like this to filter by cuisine type in angular2

```
@Pipe({
      name: 'filter',
      pure: false
 })
 export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(items: any[], selectedId: any): any {
     if(selectedId === -1)
           return items;
    return items.filter(item => item.cuisine_type[0] === selectedId);

  }
 }
```

And in the ionic view  I have used it like this

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let cat of selectedCats">
            <ion-card-header>
              {{cat}}
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
                <ion-list class="checkbox-list" *ngIf="dishes ?.length > 0">
                  <ion-item class="checkbox-item" *ngFor="let dish of dishes | filter:cat">

                    <ion-label>{{dish.title}}</ion-label>
                      <ion-checkbox [formControlName]="dish.id"></ion-checkbox>

                  </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

When I am using pipe value as static like its working

```
 <ion-item class="checkbox-item" *ngFor="let dish of dishes | filter:2140">
```

but when I am using it dynamically its not showing any result

```
<ion-item class="checkbox-item" *ngFor="let dish of dishes | filter:cat">
```

Comment: This should work, even without `pure: false`.

Comment: yes.but don't know what mistake I am doing.not working

Comment: Any error in the browser console? Does adding a `console.log('filter', selectedId);` as first line inside `transform()` get printed as expected?

Comment: no, its coming expected result as "filter  2140". no error

Comment: What about `== selectedId` instead of `=== selectedId` in `transform()`?

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. It working now with == selectedId  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not caused by Angular, but by your code

```
item.cuisine_type[0] === selectedId
```

being overly specific about accepted values

```
item.cuisine_type[0] == selectedId
```

is more forgiving by allowing type coercion before the comparison.

This means, that `cat` is probably a string `'2140'` and `item.cuisine_type[0]` a number.
If you pass it as `| filter:2140"` it's passed as number and matches `item.cuisine_type[0]`.